# Send customDimentions from Azure Application Insights with an Alert Rule

Tags: java, azure, azure-application-insights, metrics, open-telemetry

I'm new to Azure and I'm some problems with the custom metrics feature in Azure. My app is sending custom metrics signals to the Azure Application Insights. If I go to the logs in Azure I can clearly see the signal with the content represented in form of customDimentions. This signal is captured by an Azure Alert, that sends a payload to a specified webhook. The issue is that I couldn't find add the customDImentions obj to the Alert payload. I know that Alerts have custom properties, but those are static.

Does anyone know a solution or a workaround?

After sending the signal from my application I can get some information in my alert like the signal name and the value, but not its properties

Comment: can you share the code what you have tried?

Comment: @Pavan 
`private TelemetryClient telemetry = new TelemetryClient();`
`telemetry.trackMetric(new MyTelemetryObject());`

I don't the code is helpful but there you go. 
As I said, the data are arriving on azure, but in the alert rule, the payload is not populated with all the data that are in the log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Set custom properties using the `TelemetryClient`. Make sure to replace `"CustomProperty1"` and `"CustomProperty2"` with your actual custom dimension names

```java
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.TelemetryClient;
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetry.MetricTelemetry;

public class MyApp {
    private static TelemetryClient telemetry = new TelemetryClient();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Your custom telemetry object
        MyTelemetryObject customTelemetry = new MyTelemetryObject();

        // Track custom metric
        telemetry.trackMetric(new MetricTelemetry("MetricName", customTelemetry.getValue()));

        // Add custom dimensions
        telemetry.getContext().getProperties().put("CustomProperty1", customTelemetry.getCustomProperty1());
        telemetry.getContext().getProperties().put("CustomProperty2", customTelemetry.getCustomProperty2());

        // Flush telemetry data
        telemetry.flush();
    }
}
```

- Using the Kusto Query Language (KQL) to filter and extract the relevant data.

```
customDimensions.CustomProperty1 == "Value1" and customDimensions.CustomProperty2 == "Value2"
```

We need to check that the Log Analytics query includes the necessary custom dimensions in the result set.
[image]

- Update the Azure Monitor alert rule to trigger the Azure Logic App you created instead of directly sending a webhook. Set up a server or endpoint in the Java application to handle the webhook notifications sent by the Logic App.